# Debugging Library in Xcode Using XCTest Framework

Tags: xcode, xcode9, xctest

I'm new to the all-things-apple ecosystem. My google-fu cannot seem to yield an answer to this problem.

I'm trying to set breakpoints in a library/framework that uses the XCTest framework. While I can successfully set breakpoints in the unit tests themselves, I cannot set breakpoints in the library. Is there a way to set breakpoints in the Library code??

I see a lot information on ensuring that the "Debug Executable" is connected when working with an executable, I cannot find info on setting breakpoints in a library/framework project.

Hopefully this is super simple :)

Comment: Is this a 3rd party library or is it your own?

Comment: @StanislavPankevich foss library I pulled down to fix something, so I have the source.

Comment: But how are you including this library in your project? Did you drop in a .framework that was pre-built?